# Why are Ember route parameters underscore-style?

Tags: ember.js

As shown here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Ember route parameters seem to be underscores by convention. Is this so?

If so, why? Everything in the API seems to be camel case. This leads to nasty looking code.

Is there any reason not to use camel case for route parameters as well?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "route parameters" you are probably referring to dynamic segments. They indeed do use underscores for separating multiple words by convention as described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_dynamic-segments).

Why? If I would have to guess, it's probably because it is reminiscent of [ActiveRecord's foreign-key reference in Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which Yehuda Katz, one of Ember's creators, was a part of the core team for a long time. Just a theory... :)